# Error: The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine not getting fixed

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, oledbexception

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper) +1818591
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +148
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +100
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +45
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +6303166
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6303479
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +47
   NameValuePair.gvbind() +66
   NameValuePair.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +39
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5483
```

I also tried using Microsoft Ace Oledb 12.0 and tried fixing it from configuration manager by setting it to x86 and x64 but no luck. 
And also tried installing the Microsoft Access Database Engine but still no luck

Comment: I tried doing it again but no luck. Also I set the enable 32 bit property of the advance settings from IIS but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Right click on the project.
2. Click Properties.
3. Under configuration Properties > Debugging.
4. Set Run64bitRuntime to false.

Comment: If this is the answer, please mark it as answered :D hehe